# How to retrieve ContentNotes information along with LinkedEntity's information with SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I would like to implement a service that takes a lastModifiedDate as input and returns all ContentNote records which were modified after the given lastModifiedDate. The service response should have the following fields

1. ContentNote:

- Id
- Title
- Content

2. ContentVersion

- VersionNumber

3. Account (LinkedEntity)

- Id
- Zipcode

Is there a way to implement this with as few queries as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes are just content documents ("Files") with special type.
This might give you some ideas?

```
SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersion.VersionNumber, LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData,
(SELECT LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
FROM ContentDocument
WHERE FileType = 'SNOTE'
AND LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, I would like to get the object specific name from LinkedEntity. For example Account's Zipcode. Is there anyway to do that? (Updated the question)

Comment: Experiment with `TYPEOF`, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm. Maybe `SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersion.VersionNumber, LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData,
(SELECT TYPEOF LinkedEntity WHEN Account THEN Id, Name, BillingPostalCode END FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
FROM ContentDocument
WHERE FileType = 'SNOTE'
AND LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7`